# How to reduce sliding while cloth simulation?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to cover a character with a blanket.
But the blanket is too slipping while simulation.
It slips off the body and the bed and falls.
I'm trying with different options, but it doesn't help.
The blanket is slipping. What am i doing wrong?
How would you fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to change Friction values or in extreme occasion gravity... oh yes or weight of vertices in your cloth

Comment: This would be how I 'freeze' the cloth.  It allows me whatever settings are best for the fall etc and once landed, can be 'frozen' by applying the cloth modifier.  See here -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169911/is-it-possible-to-pause-cloth-simulation-and-start-at-a-later-frame/170272#170272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collision object has a *Softbody & Cloth > Friction* option, increase it:

[image]

Comment: Well, looks like this was not enough. I try the options in the fabric and girl settings. But anyway thanx for the clue. I forgot about friction in Softbody&Cloth section.